# *ngFor accessing multiple arrays Angular

Tags: angular, html-table, ngfor

I have array which contains : id and content.

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
this.tablePresetColumns = [{id: 1,content: 'Username'},{id: 2,content:'Status'}];

this.tablePresetData = [[{id: 1, content: "Budi Kurniawan"},{id: 2, content: "Busy"}]]
```

So far, I've tried these :

**Dashboard.component.html**

```
<table class="table" [ngClass]="modes">
    <thead *ngIf="columns">
     <tr>
     <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">
     {{col.content}}
     </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData ">
     <td *ngFor="let cell of row[i]"> {{cell.content}}
   </td>
   <td *ngFor="let cell of row[i]"> 
    <span class ="dot" [ngClass]="{
     'dot-yellow' : cell.content == 'Busy',
     'dot-green' : cell.content == 'Idle',
     'dot-red' : cell.content == 'Overload'}">
     </span>
   </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to access the data of my array on my component.ts, so I can show data as table format? I'm trying `*ngFor` but still can't show anything.

Comment: `row[i]` What is "i"? You should just  `*ngFor="let cell of row"`

Comment: I think that should be *ngFor="let cell of row"

Answer (score 0):

Don't need access `row[i]` just pass `*ngFor="let cell of row"` will solve your problem.

```
 <table class="table" [ngClass]="modes">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">{{col.content}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData ">
      <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> 
        <span class ="dot" [ngClass]="{
          'dot-yellow' : cell.content == 'Busy',
          'dot-green' : cell.content == 'Idle',
          'dot-red' : cell.content == 'Overload'}">
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: still can't access it sir @TheParam

Answer (score 0):

You need not to set the `i` in your row, because you have a nested `*ngFor`.

`*ngFor="let row of tablePresetColumns` - here the row is a current object of the array, so `row[i]`, wont have any value.

Just use `*ngFor="let cell of row"`.

```
<table class="table" [ngClass]="modes">
    <thead *ngIf="columns">
     <tr>
     <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">
     {{col.content}}
     </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData ">
     <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}}
   </td>
   <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> 
    <span class ="dot" [ngClass]="{
     'dot-yellow' : cell.content == 'Busy',
     'dot-green' : cell.content == 'Idle',
     'dot-red' : cell.content == 'Overload'}">
     </span>
   </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access elements of the nested array with an index, you just use `*ngFor` on the nested item.

```
<table class="table" [ngClass]="modes">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">{{col.content}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData ">
      <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> 
        <span class ="dot" [ngClass]="{
          'dot-yellow' : cell.content == 'Busy',
          'dot-green' : cell.content == 'Idle',
          'dot-red' : cell.content == 'Overload'}">
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7a3fj

Answer (score 0):

Well i have implemented this code and its working fine .Please try this and let me know if issue still persist

.html file

```
<table class="table" [ngClass]="modes">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">
            {{col.content}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>`enter code here`
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData ">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}}
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
            <span class="dot" [ngClass]="{
                                 'dot-yellow' : cell.content == 'Busy',
                                 'dot-green' : cell.content == 'Idle',
                                 'dot-red' : cell.content == 'Overload'}">
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

.ts File

```
tablePresetColumns = [{id: 1,content: 'Username'},{id: 2,content:'Status'}];
tablePresetData = [[{id: 1, content: "Budi Kurniawan"},{id: 2, content: "Busy"}]];
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORfOd.png)